# Format console readout in Aria2

Tags: batch-file, aria2

I'm using `aria2` to perform basic downloads. [In the documentation](http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#console-readout) it specifies the `console readout` format to be:

> [#2089b0     400.0KiB/33.2MiB(1%)     CN:1     DL:115.7KiB     ETA:4m51s]

This format is fairly readable, but as it's going to be used by end users, it would be easier as just:

> 400.0KiB/33.2MiB  (1%)   ETA:4m51s

As I'm using this in a batch-file, I thought about using a `for /f` loop to extract the data and then parse it. As far as I know, you can only use static data in a `for /f` loop, ie. it doesn't support formatting in *realtime* output from a command.

I *can't seem* to find any documentation on how to change the format using command line options, but **do command line options exist to change the format of the console readout?** or would I have to create modified version of `aria2` and recompile?

Comment: It may be possible to do this with `for /l` but it is tricky because of possible syncronisation issues. See this answer [Ping with timestamp](//stackoverflow.com/a/24907186) for inspiration.

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748913/format-console-readout-in-aria2). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you cannot change the format of console readout in aria2, there are no options to control it.

If you pipe the output of `aria2c`, it suppresses readout as well as log. So the best option is probably to suppress console readout with [`--show-console-readout`](http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption--show-console-readout) option set to `false`.

To reduce the number of messages printed, you can also decrease console log level with [`--console-log-level`](http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption--console-log-level).

To control how often aria2 prints current download summary, use [`--summary-interval`](http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption--summary-interval) option.

Your command can look like this:

```
aria2c --show-console-readout=false --console-log-level=warn --summary-interval=5 <url>
```

Every 5 seconds aria2 will print download stats. To filter other output you can use `find "ETA:"` and then parse it with [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).